# Is there a device for protecting your carbon-soled road shoes from the cleats?

Tags: shoes, carbon, damage, protection

I recently came across this [product](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001GSMLXE):, which is a stainless steel shield to place between your mountain cleats and your carbon soled shoes, to prevent damage to the carbon.

Has anyone seen something similar for a road shoe?

[image: Crank Brothers Shoe Shields]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a pair of [these stickers](http://www.chainreactioncycles.com/Models.aspx?ModelID=52772).

As far as I know most road cleats are plastic cleats and are not going to do significant damage to the shoe (being plastic and large rather than metal and small) so no protection is needed.

(There are some road cleats which are metal, as described in comments.)

Comment: I use the time iclic, which is a metal cleat.

Comment: @zenbike I haven't seen those before.. you learn something new every day! Are they good? I dislike my standard Shimano SL pedals because it's hard to get my shoes aligned and clipped in.

Comment: They are very good, in terms of retention and feel, but probably more likely to have issues with the connection. They must be fit very well to be easy.

Answer (score 1):

If you're really that concerned, get a roll of 3M "copter tape" and cut it to the same size as the cleat. Given the cleat should never move, the most you should get is a bit of marking where the cleat sits which you'll never see as the cleat should never move (and it's helpful when you're replacing cleats)